# amazon web service not working in server, but working from localhost

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon Web Service in my website. It works fine on localhost. I am using LAMP.

But the same file from the server showing this error:

**`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details`**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you `Consult the service documentation for details`?

Comment: @raoul: can you please tell me, where can i find service documentation.

Comment: is google broken? http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/

Comment: Also, provide more details like - which AWS module are you using - EC2? S3 etc. And check if the credentials are same in localhost and server.